# how to write fancy url with one parameter

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

i have a index page www.domainname.com and a file called all.php inside it.
i want to change it dynamically through .htaccess file.
i want from www.yourame.com/all.php?category=foo
to www.yourname.com/all/foo
what i tried so far in my .htaccess is

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index.php/?category=$1 [QSA]
```

but the result is still same in url ie.

```
www.yourname.com/all.php?category=foo
```

so how can i achieve the desired result,thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /all\.php\?category=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ all/%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^all/([^/.]+)/?$ all.php?category=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: if i am in localhost/domainname/all.php?category=poo then what to do after all previous code works grt @anubhava

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue that you are having is because you are missing a space between your rewrite and your file path.

Something like this might work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?category=$1 [QSA]
```

Comment: no result still same www.yourdomain.com/all.php?category=poo  @Get Off My Lawn

Comment: I removed the `/` that was before the `?`

Comment: not worked i also tried this RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php/all.php/?category=$1 [QSA] but not worked @Get Off My Lawn

Comment: @priyabrata You know the Rewrite Rule works so, that if you enter `www.yourname.com/all/foo` it internally rewrites to `www.yourame.com/all.php?category=foo`. And not the other way around

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule

```
 RewriteRule    ^all/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$    all.php?category=$1    [NC,L]
```

Comment: still no result   it shows www.yourdomain.com/all.php?category=poo   @sandeepsure

Answer (score 0):

ya i tried this and its works like a champ
my .htaccess file code is

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^all/([^/.]+) all.php?category=$1 [L,NC]
```

my index file code is

```
<a href="all/foo>click here</a>
```

and the result is

```
www.yourdomain.com/all/foo
```

Comment: Why are you answering your own question? This is the same answer @anubhava provided. However his answer is more complete because it allows redirect for old URL too.